# How to concatenate a parameter value with a constant string in Yaml

Tags: symfony, yaml

I have an URL defined as a parameter in `parameters.yml`. I want to create a service which is a *SOAP* client. The argument of the SOAP client is an URL for a `wsdl` file. In my case, the URL of the `wsdl` file is `"%parameter_url%"` + "?wsdl"`.

Is there a way to concatenate the "?wsdl" to a parameter already defined in YAML?

Comment: Normally, you will have a library to read from config files(yaml). I am not sure about php, but it works for other frameworks/languages.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need a concatenation character, you can append the constant directly after the parameter. For example, for a service definition in services.yml:

```
my.service:
    class: "%my.service.class%"
    arguments:     
      - "@logger", 
      - "%some_parameter%", 
      - "%parameter_url%?wsdl",
```

Comment: Not quoting a scalar starting with the '%' indicator character is deprecated since Symfony 3.1

Just adding quotes around the whole line will work: `"%parameter_url%?wsdl"`

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to concatenate two parameters. You can do it this way:

> parameters.yml

`parameter_url: XXXXX
 parameter_type: ?wsdl`

> services.yml

```
my.service:
    class: %my.service.class%
    arguments:     
        - @logger, 
        - %some_parameter%, 
        - '%parameter_url%%parameter_type%',
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on [redbirdo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302002/redbirdo) his response, since not quoting a scalar starting with the '%' indicator character is deprecated since Symfony 3.1:

```yaml
my.service:
  class: "%my.service.class%"
  arguments:
    - "@logger"
    - "%some_parameter%"
    - "%parameter_url%?wsdl"

# OR

my.service:
  class: "%my.service.class%"
  arguments: ["@logger", "%some_parameter%", "%parameter_url%?wsdl"]
```